# Regarding this part of "Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment"

Tags: c, if-statement

I'm having a problem understanding this seemingly simple piece of code, that is represented in the book "[Advanced Programming in the Unix Environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Programming_in_the_Unix_Environment)":

```
#include "apue.h"

int main (void)
{
    int c;

    while((c = getc(stdin)) != EOF)
        if(putc(c, stdout) == EOF)    // This bugs me
            err_sys("output error");
    if(ferror(stdin))
        err_sys("input error");

    exit(0);
}
```

The book states that this program copies standard input to standard output, using *getc* and *putc*. The part I understand is, that the program prints "output error", when there's no character to output, but I don't see the code anywhere that actually transfers the input to the output (it seems that the *if* loop is missing the *else* block that actually outputs the character).

Is there maybe some fundamental thing that I don't recognize here?

The piece of code below is how I see it. To my mind the stuff inside the *if* comparison is just a ***comparison***, not an actual process that is done. That's why there should be that extra line "putc(c, stdout);" that actually puts character to standard output. What is wrong with my logic?

```
if(putc(c, stdout) != EOF){
    putc(c, stdout);
    else{
        err_sys("output error");
    }
}
```

Comment: The `if` calls `putc` and the `while` calls `getc`, so what are you missing?

Comment: It just wraps the function in an `if`.  Then it compares the return value of the function with a special value (`EOF`).  Its purpose it to conserve space.

Answer (score 3):

> Is there maybe some fundamental thing that I don't recognize here?

There definitely is.

`(c = getc(stdin)) != EOF`

reads a character from `stdin` into `c`.

```
if(putc(c, stdout) == EOF)
    err_sys("output error");
```

outputs the contents of `c` to `stdout` using `putc` and calls `error_sys` if the call failed.

Answer (score 0):

> i don't see the code anywhere that actually transfers the input to the output

That's the call to `putc`, which writes a character to the output stream.

> the program prints "output error", when there's no character to output

No, it prints that if the call to `putc` failed, indicating an error in the output stream.